# How to replace certain values in a column with the values in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

[image: Dataframe sample]

Keep in mind the 'None' value is a string so can't use .fillna

df[df['TRIPLINE'] == 'None']

I want to fill these string values with the corresponding value in the 'LINE' column

Comment: share the data in text format. not as an imagr

Answer (score 0):

As long as None is truly a string and not a np.nan or None you can use `np.where()`

```
import numpy as np
df['TRIPLINE'] = np.where(df['TRIPLINE'] == 'None', df['LINE'], df['TRIPLINE'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.loc` with your `== 'None'` mask:

```
act_thruput_raw.loc[act_thruput_raw['TRIPLINE'] == 'None', 'TRIPLINE'] = act_thruput_raw['LINE']
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```py
df['TRIPLINE'] = df['TRIPLINE'].mask(df['TRIPLINE'] == 'None', df['LINE'])
```